# Creating a user profile with Omniauth hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, profile

I'm trying to pull out profile information from my user model. Currently I'm using Omniauth (twitter & facebook) to create users and just writing all the information to the user table... this works great, however I was told that proper Rails convention is to separate the user & profile.

After a couple of days of trial and error, I'm having trouble getting the has_one relationship working while creating a profile with the users info from the Omniauth hash.

I've tried to user a before_filter to automagically create a profile before the user is create, which properly creates the user_id foreign key in the profiles table, however I can't seem to get any of the omniauth hash data to write.

my sessions controller:

```
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

  if user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Signed In'
  else
    user = User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    redirect_to profile_path(user), :notice => 'Please verify your profile'
  end
```

in my user model:

```
before_create :create_profile

  def self.create_profile(auth)
    create! do |profile|
      profile.user_id = session[:user_id]
      profile.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      profile.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      profile.nickname = auth["info"]["nickname"]
      profile.location = auth["info"]["location"]
      profile.image = auth["info"]["image"]
     end
   end

   ...
```

The other option I tried was to write the profile data with the profile model... which works for the Omniauth hash data, but wont write the correct user_id (so no foreign key)

profile.rb

```
def self.create_profile_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |profile|
    profile.user_id = session[:user_id]
    profile.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    profile.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    profile.nickname = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    profile.location = auth["info"]["location"]
    profile.image = auth["info"]["image"]
  end
end
```

Comment: I could be wrong but the `before_create` could be messing you up. Since your User `has_one` Profile, if you're creating a Profile before a User that won't work since you'll never get the User ID assigned to the Profile. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.